# Filter a list in-place with the angular $filter service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I have a couple of filters which are working fine, and which I've so far used only through pipes in my HTML templates. Now, I have a use case where I'd like to do the same kind of filtering, but in the controller of a directive.

I know I can use the angular `$filter` service to get access to the filters, using

```
var filtered = $filter('myFilter')(unfiltered);
```

but my use-case requires that the lists are filtered *in-place*, i.e. I can not re-bind the variable (lest I would loose the bindings to other places where the same variable might be used).

I can't find anything about this in [the official docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter), but I don't want to give up hope just yet =)

Comment: That is a very un-Angular way of doing things. If you're talking about bindings on a single scope, just rebind it. If it's shared between scopes, use a service. Why can't you rebind the value?

Comment: why u cannot just remove all from unfiltered and then add all from filtered to unfiltered?

Comment: really not clear what the higher level issue is here. More details on the binding problem would help

Comment: If you lose some bindings then you have another problem anyway, imho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are describing a case where replacing the entire array (or object) in a child scope, the parent, or sibling scopes lose the connection to the array. This happens because of the nature of scope inheritance. If you have a scope, you place an array on that scope, then have two child scopes, and replace the array on one of them, then the other child scope and parent scope will 'loose the connection'.
There several ways to solve this. Here are a couple:

1. Wrap the array with an object on the parent scope. Then reference the array in the child scopes via the object. If you do that you can change the entire array and all controllers will still reference the same array.

instead of: $scope.someArr

```
use: $scope.wrapper = {
   someArr: SomeArr
}
```

then: on the child scope reference: $childScope.wrapper.someArr

2. You can modify the original array. Filter into a new array, then concat the arguments into an array, and apply splice:

example code:

```
//originalArr
var newArr// = new filtered array
var args = [0, originalArr.length].concat(newArr);
originalArr.splice.apply(this, args);
```

This code is conceptual only and has not been tested. The idea is that splice handles the original array and the reference to the array on all scopes stays the same.

Comment: These are two good suggestions, one of which will definitely solve my problem. As it turned out, we had to solve this differently for now, so I haven't gotten the chance to test this properly, but since it seems like at least the second version, or some modification of it, should do the job, I'll mark this as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: I stumbled on this problem again, and was able to solve it using the second approach; however, I had to change the code to `Array.prototype.splice.apply(originalArr, [0, originalArr.length].concat(newArr))` to get it working.